# Group By after parsing a message in AWS cloudwatch insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have messages which are like below, the following message is one of the messages (have so many JSON formats which are not at all related to this)

```
request body to the server {'sender': '65ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558834', 'message': 'hello'}
```

I would like to group of these messages based on sender (alphanumeric value) which is enclosed in JSON.

Comment: What do you want to do with the group? Count the number of items in each group? Something else? What's your expected output?

Comment: I wanted to know how many messages are coming from each user and also how many distinct users in selected interval.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CloudWatch Logs Insights query:

```
fields @message |
filter @message like 'request body to the server' |
parse @message "'sender': '*', 'message'" as sender |
stats count(*) by sender
```

Query results:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|               sender               | count(*) |
|------------------------------------|----------|
| 65ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558834 |     4    |
| 55ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558834 |     3    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you harish,                                                                                                                                            
**Date is 2020-06-25 Request from User: 5044fbb94f2a6200644797dd0210c787 , User name is: pareti, and message: i want to create a ticket**

Can we extract this as well? I want user name from this line

Comment: I think `fields @timestamp, @message
| filter user_name like "pareti"` should work.

Comment: @RajeevUppala `fields @message | filter @message like 'Request from User' | parse @message 'User name is: *, and message' as username`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html).

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like "65ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558834"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

it will filter all the messages limit to 20 that send by `65ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558834`.

**update:**

suppose the JSON log formate is this

```
{
    "sender": "65ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558835",
    "message": "Hi"
}
```

Now I want to count number of messages from `65ddd20eac244AAe619383e4d8cb558835`

> how many messages are coming from each user?

so simple you can run the query

```
stats count(sender) by sender |
# To filter only message the contain sender, to avoid lambda default logs
filter @message like "sender"
```

[image]
if you want to see messages as well then modify the query a bit

```
stats count(*) by sender, message |

filter @message like "sender"
```

Here `@message` refers to whole to index where `message` refer to the JSON object `message`.

[image]

**count_distinct**

> Returns the number of unique values for the field. If the field has
> very high cardinality (contains many unique values), the value
> returned by `count_distinct` is just an approximation.

> how many distinct users in the selected interval?

It will list distinct users in `3hr` of interval

```
 stats count_distinct(sender) as distinct_sender by bin(3hr) as interval
```

[image]

Comment: I am doing this already, I wanted to get only such value which is alphanumeric and results will be grouped with the same alphanumeric value

Comment: okay got it, updating answer that might help what you are looking for